# Vue 3 reactive property value not updating in template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue-router

I have a component with reactive property that updates when vue route change in console log I can see that reactive value changes but not in the template. How can I make the template update?

**Code**

```
<template>
  <el-breadcrumb separator-class="el-icon-arrow-right">
    <el-breadcrumb-item
      v-for="(route, index) in routes"
      :key="index"
      :to="{ path: route.path }"
    >
      {{ route.meta.title }}
    </el-breadcrumb-item>
  </el-breadcrumb>
</template>

<script>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import { reactive, watch } from '@vue/runtime-core';
export default {
  name: "BreadCrumbs",
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute();
    let routes = reactive(route.matched);

    watch(() => route.name, () => {
      routes = route.matched;
      console.log(routes);
    });

    return {
      routes
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `routes`? Did `route.matched` not work in the template?

Comment: @PenAndPapers Not related to this question: I have created an answer regarding the question you asked a few minutes ago, which got deleted. I think it was a good question so I answered it. View the working answer on https://jsfiddle.net/9naj6mcu.